# Overriding admin views in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know you can override WooCommerce core templates by defining your own and naming them the same as the core templates. But what I'd like to do is customizing some bits of an admin view, namely the Order Edit screen.

The file I would like to tweak is /includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php but obviously I don't want to apply the changes in the core file as my changes would be lost on a next WooCommerce update.

Is there a way I can create my own html-order-item.php file that would run instead of the core one? I've been searching quite a while now but I can't figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: Now i am looking for the same problem what you have did and let me know the best solution. @Laurent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have a hard time removing features from those screens. That would require replacing too much of the code for the plugin to be upgradeable later. I supposed you could hide or change the look of some with css styles.

What you can do, is add your own features at various `do_action` calls. For instance, in `html-order-items.php` where the file you mentioned is included you have the following action call:

```
include( 'html-order-item.php' );

do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_' . $item['type'] . '_html', $item_id, $item );
```

you can hook in your own fields there.

In `html-order-item.php` you have three more hooks:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', $item_id, $item, $_product ) ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', $item_id, $item, $_product ) ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', $_product, $item, absint( $item_id ) ); ?>
```

You might also need to look up the hooks where data is saved.

EDIT: adding items to the meta fields list to be skipped:

```
function remove_order_item_meta_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields[] = '_subscription_period';
    $fields[] = '_subscription_interval';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'remove_order_item_meta_fields' );
```

Comment: Well, what I'm actually trying to do is this:

1) Remove the sku 
by removing echo ( $_product && $_product->get_sku() ) ? esc_html( $_product->get_sku() ) . ' &ndash; ' : '';)

2) Extend the // Skip hidden core fields. The woothemes subscription plugin adds some additional meta as _subscription_period, _subscription_interval and so on. Would like to hide these too.

It's easily done by adding them in the core file line:60 but I don't really understand how I can implement this by using a hook. Any suggestions? :-)

Thanks

Comment: 1) this removal can be done via css styles. Enqueue your own stylesheet for the admin side and set the sku elements to `diplay:none`. 2) They apply filters to remove meta fields, you can make additions there. See the post edit for details.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try that.

Comment: Thanks for this examples, were helpful, I really think they need to improve these views with some filters to make them more manipulable for devs, it's 2020 and I really had a bad time adding custom data to those views!